# Check if the form is submitted or not with PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this select box to select an option from it and display contents according to selection. 
I am not using a submit button submit this form, thats why I have added onsubmit/onchange feature to this drop down box.

This is my drop down box :

```
<select class="select" name="type" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();">
    <option value="1">Tutor</option>
    <option value="2">Institute</option>
    <option value="3">Student</option>
</select>
```

can anybody tell me how I can check this select box have selected an option or not with Javascript? Of course I need to make sure to check if the form was submitted or not with PHP.

Comment: PHP is server side. If you need to check something in the client side, you need Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use isset

```
if (isset($_POST["type"])) ...
```

Comment: Yes I tried it.. something like this -  if (isset($_POST["type"])) {  
  echo 'good';
 } else {
  echo 'bad';
 } always script going to 'bad';

Comment: Have you set the method attribute of the form tag to post? if not, you could use $_GET instead

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery like this:

```
$("select[name='type']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ""){
        $(this).parent().submit();   
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<select class="select" name="type">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="1">Tutor</option>
    <option value="2">Institute</option>
    <option value="3">Student</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: See,  my form is submitting with onchange or onsubmit. There is not a submit button. when select an option form should be check.

Comment: @TNK should it be checked in javascript or PHP?

Comment: @TNK yes, but your question asks PHP

Comment: yes sorry about it.. So can we have a solution with javascript

Comment: @TNK if you add jquery libary then my sollution is above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25604/discussion-between-tnk-and-s-lenders)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make an 'echo' from the PHP code?

```
echo $_POST['type'];
```

From your PHP code. I'm not sure if this is correct, but I believe you should get some response: '1', '2' or '3', depending on the value submitted.
I don't remember very well the Radio, forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the POST being submitted from the select's  name and then check it's an integer like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['type'] && is_int($_POST['type']) )
  {
   // It's been submitted and you can do your processing 
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: although I'm not a javascript programmer, I think you need to have an id='form[0]' after the form name and an id='type' after the select name... also you might want to try changing your form[0] to something like name='myform' id='myform' (but I'm guessing here whether you can use an array in the submit form name or not.)